# Nvidia nvcc -v not installed

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I installed `cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local` on Ubuntu 16.10. When I import tensorflow in python, everything seems fine:

```
Python 2.7.12+ (default, Sep 17 2016, 12:08:02) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160914] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
```

but I get the following when I try `nvcc -v`. Also I tried installing the Chainer framework and it says it can't find `nvcc`.

```
nvcc -v
/usr/bin/nvcc: line 1: /bin: Is a directory
/usr/bin/nvcc: line 2: cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb: command not found
/usr/bin/nvcc: line 3: cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb: command not found
/usr/bin/nvcc: line 4: cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb: command not found
/usr/bin/nvcc: line 5: cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local_8.0.44-1_amd64.deb: command not found
/usr/bin/nvcc: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/nvcc: line 6: ` * This source code and/or documentation ("Licensed Deliverables") are'
```

Is the output from `nvcc -v` ok? I'm guessing it's not. How do I properly install nvcc?

Comment: Your posted _error mesage_ doesn't seem to be complete.

Comment: DId you add it to your `.bashrc` file ?

Comment: @George That's the entire error message.

Comment: @George What should I add?

Comment: The path to _cuda_.

Comment: @George Ok. Do I add the path to the `cudnn.h`, which is in `~/cuda/include` or just add `~/cuda`?

Comment: Do you have _cuda_ in `/usr/local` ?

Comment: @George Yes. I just moved the folder to there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51153/discussion-between-george-and-soubriquet).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add *cuda* path to your `/home/username/.bashrc` file to setup the CUDA environment:

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-7.5 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64 

PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH} 
export PATH
```

Please change the version numbers to yours and `source` your `/home/username/.bashrc` file.

source:

http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda7.5-ubuntu

Comment: Just followed those instructions you posted and got the same error. :/